# Proof check for completeness

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, cauchy-sequences

I'd like to see if the proof I have is adequate.

**Statement.** Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach space, the product $X\times Y$ is a vector space under coordinate operations with norm 
$$
\|(x,y)\| = \|x\|_X +\|y\|_Y.
$$ 
Show that we have a Banach space with the defined norm.

**Proof.** Since $X$ and $Y$ are both Banach spaces, then $\forall \, \varepsilon>0 \ \exists N$ such that if  $n>N$ then 
$$
\|x_n -x\|_X < \frac{\varepsilon}{4}\quad\text{and}\quad\|y_n-y\|_Y < \frac{\varepsilon}{4}.
$$

Hence if we start of with a Cauchy sequence $\{(x_n,y_n)\}$ we have:

$\begin{eqnarray*}
\|(x_n,y_n)-(x_m,y_m)\| &=& \|(x_n-x_m,y_n-y_m\|
\\ &=& \|x_n-x_m\|_X + \|y_n-y_m\|_Y
\\ &\leq& \|x_n-x\|_X + \|x-x_m\|_X + \|y_n-y\|_Y + \|y-y_m\|_Y
\\ &<& \frac{\varepsilon}{4} + \frac{\varepsilon}{4}+ \frac{\varepsilon}{4}+ \frac{\varepsilon}{4} = \varepsilon
\end{eqnarray*}$

So we see that our Cauchy sequence is convergent.

Comment: In addition to what @Yiorgos stated

To see that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \{(x_n, y_n)\} = (x, y)$ 

we have $\begin{eqnarray*}
||(x_n,y_n)-(x,y)|| &=& ||(x_n-x,y_n-y)||
\\ &=& ||x_n-x||_X + ||y_n-y||_Y
\\ &<& \frac{\varepsilon}{2} + \frac{\varepsilon}{2} = \varepsilon
\end{eqnarray*}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your proof, you should start with a Cauchy sequence $\{(x_n,y_n)\}\subset X\times Y$ and show that this sequence is convergent in $X\times Y$.

First observe that if $\{(x_n,y_n)\}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $X\times Y$, then both $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ are Cauchy sequences in $X$ and $Y$ respectively, since
$$
\|x_m-x_n\|+\|y_m-y_n\|=\|(x_m,y_m)-(x_n,y_n)\|<\varepsilon.
$$

Now, as $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ are Cauchy sequences in $X$ and $Y$ respectively, and  $X$ and $Y$ are Banach spaces, then they converge say to $x$ and $y$, respectively.

Finally, show that  $\{(x_n,y_n)\}$ converges to $(x,y)$, and thus every Cauchy sequence in $X\times Y$ is convergent.